# Nested JSON to CSV Conversion

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I am receiving few JSON responses from REST APIs, format of my response is following :-

```
{
 "headings": [
   "ACCOUNT_ID",
   "date",
   "FB Likes"
 ],
 "rows": [
   [
    "My Account",
    "1435708800000",
     117
   ],
   [
   "My Account",
   "1435795200000",
   99
   ],
   [
   "My Account",
   "1435708800000",
   7
  ]
]
}
```

Where columns are AccountID, Date and FB_Likes, and I am trying to convert it into csv, I have tried many different iterations but with no succees.

Please help me with this

One of my used scripts were

```
with open('Account_Insights_12Jan.json') as fi:
data = json.load(fi)

 json_array=data

columns = set()
for item in json_array:
   columns.update(set(item))

# writing the data on csv
with open('Test_14Jan.csv', 'w', newline='') as fo:
writer = csv.writer(fo)

writer.writerow(list(columns))
for item in json_array:
    row = []
    for c in columns:
        if c in item: row.append(str(item[c]))
        else: row.append('')
    writer.writerow(row)
```

N I am receiving a error from it, I copied it from somewhere, Pls explain how to convert it

Hi Again

```
{
 "headings": [
"POST_ ID",
"POST_COMMENT_COUNT"
 ],
 "rows": [
 [
  {
    "postId": 188365573,
    "messageId": 198365562,
    "accountId": 214,
    "messageType": 2,
    "channelType": "TWITTER",
    "accountType": "TWITTER",
    "taxonomy": {
      "campaignId": "2521_4",
      "clientCustomProperties": {
        "PromotionChannelAbbreviation": [
          "3tw"
        ],
        "PromotionChannels": [
          "Twitter"
        ],
        "ContentOwner": [
          "Audit"
        ],
        "Location": [
          "us"
        ],
        "Sub_Category": [
          "dbriefs"
        ],
        "ContentOwnerAbbreviation": [
          "aud"
        ],
        "PrimaryPurpose_Outcome": [
          "Engagement"
        ],
        "PrimaryPurposeOutcomeAbbv": [
          "eng"
        ]
      },
      "partnerCustomProperties": {},
      "tags": [],
      "urlShortnerDomain": "2721_spr.ly"
    },
    "approval": {
      "approvalOption": "NONE",
      "comment": ""
    },
    "status": "SENT",
    "createdDate": 1433331585000,
    "scheduleDate": 1435783440000,
    "version": 4,
    "deleted": false,
    "publishedDate": 1435783441000,
    "statusID": "6163465412728176",
    "permalink": "https://twitter.com/Acctg/status/916346541272498176",
    "additional": {
      "links": []
    }
  },
  0
],
[
  {
    "postId": 999145171,
    "messageId": 109145169,
    "accountId": 21388,
    "messageType": 2,
    "channelType": "TWITTER",
    "accountType": "TWITTER",
    "taxonomy": {
      "campaignId": "2521_4",
      "clientCustomProperties": {
        "PromotionChannelAbbreviation": [
          "3tw"
        ],
        "Eminence_Registry_Number": [
          "1000159"
        ],
        "PromotionChannels": [
          "Twitter"
        ],
        "ContentOwner": [
          "Ctr. Health Solutions"
        ],
        "Location": [
          "us"
        ],
        "Sub_Category": [
          "fraud"
        ],
        "ContentOwnerAbbreviation": [
          "chs"
        ],
        "PrimaryPurpose_Outcome": [
          "Awareness"
        ],
        "PrimaryPurposeOutcomeAbbv": [
          "awa"
        ]
      },
      "partnerCustomProperties": {},
      "tags": [],
      "urlShortnerDomain": "2521_spr.ly"
    },
    "approval": {
      "approvalOption": "NONE",
      "comment": ""
    },
    "status": "SENT",
    "createdDate": 1434983660000,
    "scheduleDate": 1435753800000,
    "version": 4,
    "deleted": false,
    "publishedDate": 1435753801000,
    "statusID": "616222222198407168",
    "permalink": "https://twitter.com/Health/status/6162222221984070968",
    "additional": {
      "links": []
    }
  },
  0
]   
}
```

Please consider this JSON response as well
Thanks Again fr all the help,  You are a savior!

Response will look Like following. It is a sample output since there are many columns, I am including few of them. My bad, I dont know how to share an excel output

Post ID,MessageID,AccountID,messageType,accountType,Channel Type
188365573,198365562,214,2,Twitter,Twitter

---

999145171,109145169,21388,2,Twitter,Twitter

The code in process is

```
csvdata= open('Data_table2.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvdata, delimiter=',')
csvwriter.writerow(header)


for i in range(0,70):
  csvwriter.writerow(data1["rows"][i][0].values())

csvdata.close()
```

But not working successfully, because of many nested version and also, in some of the responses we have some headers which need to e checked and if it is not there then make a new header for that

Thanks Again for all the help!
Manu

Comment: Define what the result is supposed to look like first and foremost.

Answer (score 1):

First, install pandas:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then, use pandas to create a DataFrame object using the data you get from response. When the object is created you will be able to convert it to csv or xls file, set 'index=False' to prevent adding indices into an output file.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('data_new.json') as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data['rows'],columns=data['headings'])
    df.to_csv('data_table.csv', index=False)
```

Output example:

```
ACCOUNT_ID,date,FB Likes
My Account,1435708800000,117
My Account,1435795200000,99
My Account,1435708800000,7
```

Comment: Answers consisting only of code, without explanation, are considered less useful. Please consider adding some explanatory text.

Comment: You might need to install pandas first. Do it with: `$ pip install pandas`

Comment: Hi Roman- It just worked like a Magic, I have no words to say thanks to you, I have been looking for this everywhere! Thanks Again. But this is where my problem starts, I have some more deep nested API Json responses, which even didn't work with this code as well. If possible, I would request please look at the above edited question of me, i have included the other Json reponses as well. You are a savior

Comment: All thanks for advices. @manusharma Hi, please specify how the output should look like, because now the response looks much more difficult.

Comment: Hi Roman- Thanks for showing the real concern with the issue, I have edited my question with the sample output. Please see, how can we go with that!

Comment: Hi Roman- I have written a code from myself to solve that, though I am still not completely successful, because of nested version.. See my code in edited que

Answer (score 0):

Missed the python requirement, but if you are willing to call external program, this will still work. 
Please note, that jq >= 1.5 is required for this to work.

```
cat YourJsonFile | jq -r ' [ .rows[][0] | to_entries  | map(.key), map(.value | tostring) ] |  .[0,range(1;length;2)]|@csv'

# Lets break it down
jq -r  #  disable escaping and quoting
   ' [ # this will add create an array
      .rows[][0] # select rows (from object, [] it's array, 
                 # and [0] first element in that array)
      | to_entries # convert it to key, value object
      | map(.key), map(.value | tostring) # select key and value 
                            # (value is converted to string)
                            # this is the step that needs '-r' option to jq
      ] # close array. We now have alternating "header" and "data" rows
      |  .[0,range(1;length;2)] # select from current (.), first (0) and 
                                # with range function every second row
                                # starting from one
      |@csv # convert resulting json to csv
      '      #  Done
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/